# How to check if customer is logged in and get customer Id in magento 2

Tags: customer, magento-2.0.7

How can i check if the customer has logged in to the magento and get the customer details like `id, first name, last name, etc.`,

I have tried this in 2 ways

1). Using the session in a block as below

```
protected $_session;
protected $_context;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
) {     
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_session = $session;
} 


public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
{
    return $this->_session->isLoggedIn();
}

public function getCustomerId(){
    return $this->_session->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

call to the function isCustomerLoggedIn() gives boolean false and call to getCustomerId() returns NULL.

2). Using Object Manager in layout

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $om->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(); 
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); // get Customer Group Id
}
```

This way gave the customer `Id, Name, Email, Group Id` of the previous logged in customer but not the current customer.

Can any one help to get the currently logged in customer details.

Comment: I have checked the marked link and did not work for me. As mentioned in the post first method yielded to Not logged in and second gave the session details of the previous logged customer.

Comment: $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSession->getId();
}

-----------------------------
Remove this   getCustomer()
$customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
replace with
$customerSession->getId();

Answer (score 5):

Try with changing the session object

```
protected $_session;
protected $_context;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
) {     
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();
} 


public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
{
    $session = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');    
    return $session->isLoggedIn();
}

public function getCustomerId(){
    $session = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');    
    return $session->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

In this method replace create from get

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(); 
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); // get Customer Group Id
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but 'get' returned false on call of $customerSession->isLoggedIn()

Comment: The same code is working for me. It may be a cache issue. Please remove all cache from admin and var/cache. Also remove all cookie of your browser and try it in fresh browser.

Comment: Checked removing the cache, cookies, browser history but still the same no result

Comment: not working for me...

Comment: not working in magento 2.2.6

Comment: $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerSession->getId();
}

-----------------------------
Remove this   getCustomer()
$customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
replace with
$customerSession->getId();

Answer (score 3):

Finally I was able to get the customer details using the session in the block. And placing the cacheable attribute for the block specified in the layout as below and it started working.

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Sample" name="sample" template="sample.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

Comment: Do not use `cacheable="false"`. This will disable FPC for that page